# From Faraday's Paradox to the design of a One Piece Axial Flux Motor

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, thought-experiment

My question is introduced through the following picture:

[image]

In the thought experiment a) a Faraday  copper Disc with a magnetic field attached to it (out of page) is rotated clockwise. A Lorenz force will separate the charge in the disc. Then the disc is partitioned as showed with insulating traces, leaving only some copper patches to co-rotate with the magnetic field. We formulate the following questions:

### Questions

- is there charge separation in the small copper patches in figure a) ?
- one of the patches is taken separately in the experiment b) . A small copper plate in a local co-moving magnetic field is rotated as shown. Is there charge separation in the copper plate?
- Assuming the above answers are YES, then in c) again a copper plate is situated in a constant magnetic field $\vec{B}$. If one separates the charges (in the copper plate) with an electric field $\vec{E}$, will the small plate start rotating?

Comment: You need to ask individual questions one at a time on this site.

Comment: well ... they are related, the first two are basically only introducing the third. I can introduce them (the first two) as assumptions ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, there is a separation of charges. See the Hall effect, which in principle is no different from the Lorentz force. What you are describing is an electric generator. For the generator to work effectively, you need an input and output of electrons that are subject to the Lorentz force between the magnetic field.
- Yes. See [homopolar motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homopolar_motor).
- Yes. This is how an electric motor works.

Comment: Have you considered the fact that the magnetic field is fixed attached to the piece? I am considering in the question that the magnets are "glued" to the rotating piece.

Comment: Isn’t that the homopolar motor? I think so.

Comment: It seems that a device can be made (with no rotating parts) which allows the balancing of a rod on one tip, by properly using two orthogonal such devices.